# Printing page with bootstrap 3

Tags: printing, twitter-bootstrap-3, dpi

I've been looking through a lot of answers here on stackoverflow that semi-cover what I'm wondering about, but haven't found anything that worked for me.

I understand that the printing page is about 550 px for A4 and therefor bootstrap will use the styles and layout usually used for mobile devices.

When I use Ctrl+P for my web page, the printable page looks just like the mobile version of my page. But how do I make it look like the desktop version? (media > 1024 px) Is there a way to do this?

I know I can change the css specifically for print. But how to solve this thing with the bootstrap 3 grid system? The width on my divs gets based on what I have added for col-xs, but I want print to use the layout (width) for col-md

**Edit:** After I have been struggeling with this for some more hours I realize that it might be more complex than I first expected. Just changing the width doesn't solve it for me. Many of my divs has the syntax of

```
<div class="md-right sm-right xs-down col-md-1 col-sm-2 box"></div>
```

or

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
```

The page looks good in XS for small devices, but printing in XS makes many elements look gigantic. So the question remains. Is there a way to make the printing page look the same as the layout for medium or large devices? Or do I have to make the printing css without using bootstrap grid system and add static widths in pt for all elements to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem using an own print.css file without all the responsive bootstrap stuff included. Only included some of the necessary bootstrap things with show and hide.

Answer (score 72):

It would be helpful to provide a JSBin. Anyway, since I had this layout in JSBin with col-sm-(asterisk), you can just change all the -sm- to -xs- in between the print media query. All percentages are the same at every breakpoint, so changing sm to xs will print that and ignore the other col-(asterisk) classes. Ahh, I read the post now, you'll need to change all the col-sm to col-md in this and then use !important, that should do it. The xs col are outside media queries, so that's why this is happening.

http://jsbin.com/AzICaQes/5

```
@media print {

.col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
  float: left;
}
.col-sm-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-sm-11 {
  width: 91.66666666666666%;
}
.col-sm-10 {
  width: 83.33333333333334%;
}
.col-sm-9 {
  width: 75%;
}
.col-sm-8 {
  width: 66.66666666666666%;
}
.col-sm-7 {
  width: 58.333333333333336%;
}
.col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col-sm-5 {
  width: 41.66666666666667%;
}
.col-sm-4 {
  width: 33.33333333333333%;
 }
 .col-sm-3 {
   width: 25%;
 }
 .col-sm-2 {
   width: 16.666666666666664%;
 }
 .col-sm-1 {
  width: 8.333333333333332%;
 }

  }
```

Comment: Yes of course! Why didn't I think of that :)
I will try it out and collaborate. I will update the ticket when I have tested it. Thank you

Comment: You'll also need to add the push and pulls to the print if you used them. Please vote on this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's still some tweeking with the print css to make it look good, but the main issue was the width stuff. When I see the answer it's obvious, but sometimes you just get stuck on the things right in front of you. Can't vote yet, but at least I marked it as an answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yep. I get brain farts on the easiest stuff sometimes. I make easy complicated depending on the time of day and coffee!

Answer (score 9):

Actually, all you need to add (to user.css) is this:

```
@media print {

  @page {                
    size: A4;
    margin: 0mm;
  }

  html, body {
    width: 1024px;
  }

  body {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

While you're at it, consider using all these settings for bootstrap 3

```
@media print {

  @page {                
    size: A4;
    margin: 0mm;
  }

  html, body {
    width: 1024px;
  }

  body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 1em;
    word-spacing:1px;
    letter-spacing:0.2px;
    font: 14px "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    background:white;
    color:black;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }

  /* avoid page-breaks inside a listingContainer*/
  .listingContainer{
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }

  h1 {
    font: 28px "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  }

  h2 {
    font: 24px "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  }

  h3 {
    font: 20px "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  }

  /* Improve colour contrast of links */
  a:link, a:visited {
    color: #781351
  }

  /* URL */
  a:link, a:visited {
    background: transparent;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  a[href]:after {
    content: "" !important;
  }

  a[href^="http://"] {
    color:#000;
  }

  #header {
    height:75px;
    font-size: 24pt;
    color:black
  }
}
```

Comment: To also print all tabs on a single page do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13964669/381082 and in Asp.Net MVC replace @ with @@ as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7027543/381082. I'm extremely grateful for this answer. My 6 page printout was reduced to 2 pages with this CSS!

Answer (score 2):

For those who use bootstrap mixins to create columns like this (sass version):

```
@include make-sm-column(3, 0);
```

it won't be enough to overwrite the styles for columns classes like Christina suggests. The only simple solution I've found was to change $screen-sm in _variables.scss to 595px and recompile bootstrap.css

So, find this code in _variables.scss:

```
$screen-sm:                  768px !default;
$screen-sm-min:              $screen-sm !default;
```

and change it to this:

```
// decrease min-width to fix print layout issue
$screen-sm:                  595px !default; 
$screen-sm-min:              $screen-sm !default;
```

then in your _print.scss

```
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0;
}
@media print {

  html, body {
    width: 768px;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  // .. your custom styles for print layout

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add This css style in your print.css file

```
    @page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 40px;
}


    @media print {
    html,
    body {
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;
    }
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {}
    .col-sm-1,
    .col-sm-2,
    .col-sm-3,
    .col-sm-4,
    .col-sm-5,
    .col-sm-6,
    .col-sm-7,
    .col-sm-8,
    .col-sm-9,
    .col-sm-10,
    .col-sm-11,
    .col-sm-12,
    .col-md-1,
    .col-md-2,
    .col-md-3,
    .col-md-4,
    .col-md-5,
    .col-md-6,
    .col-md-7,
    .col-md-8,
    .col-md-9,
    .col-md-10,
    .col-md-11,
    .col-smdm-12 {
        float: left;
    }
    .col-sm-12,
    .col-md-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .col-sm-11,
    .col-md-11 {
        width: 91.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-10,
    .col-md-10 {
        width: 83.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-9,
    .col-md-9 {
        width: 75%;
    }
    .col-sm-8,
    .col-md-8 {
        width: 66.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-7,
    .col-md-7 {
        width: 58.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-6,
    .col-md-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-sm-5,
    .col-md-5 {
        width: 41.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-4,
    .col-md-4 {
        width: 33.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-3,
    .col-md-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .col-sm-2,
    .col-md-2 {
        width: 16.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-1,
    .col-md-1 {
        width: 8.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-pull-12 {
        right: 100%;
    }
    .col-sm-pull-11 {
        right: 91.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-pull-10 {
        right: 83.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-pull-9 {
        right: 75%;
    }
    .col-sm-pull-8 {
        right: 66.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-pull-7 {
        right: 58.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-pull-6 {
        right: 50%;
    }
    .col-sm-pull-5 {
        right: 41.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-pull-4 {
        right: 33.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-pull-3 {
        right: 25%;
    }
    .col-sm-pull-2 {
        right: 16.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-pull-1 {
        right: 8.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-pull-0 {
        right: auto;
    }
    .col-sm-push-12 {
        left: 100%;
    }
    .col-sm-push-11 {
        left: 91.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-push-10 {
        left: 83.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-push-9 {
        left: 75%;
    }
    .col-sm-push-8 {
        left: 66.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-push-7 {
        left: 58.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-push-6 {
        left: 50%;
    }
    .col-sm-push-5 {
        left: 41.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-push-4 {
        left: 33.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-push-3 {
        left: 25%;
    }
    .col-sm-push-2 {
        left: 16.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-push-1 {
        left: 8.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-push-0 {
        left: auto;
    }
    .col-sm-offset-12 {
        margin-left: 100%;
    }
    .col-sm-offset-11 {
        margin-left: 91.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-offset-10 {
        margin-left: 83.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-offset-9 {
        margin-left: 75%;
    }
    .col-sm-offset-8 {
        margin-left: 66.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-offset-7 {
        margin-left: 58.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-offset-6 {
        margin-left: 50%;
    }
    .col-sm-offset-5 {
        margin-left: 41.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-offset-4 {
        margin-left: 33.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-offset-3 {
        margin-left: 25%;
    }
    .col-sm-offset-2 {
        margin-left: 16.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-offset-1 {
        margin-left: 8.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-offset-0 {
        margin-left: 0%;
    }
    .visible-xs {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .hidden-xs {
        display: block !important;
    }
    table.hidden-xs {
        display: table;
    }
    tr.hidden-xs {
        display: table-row !important;
    }
    th.hidden-xs,
    td.hidden-xs {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }
    .hidden-xs.hidden-print {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .hidden-sm {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .visible-sm {
        display: block !important;
    }
    table.visible-sm {
        display: table;
    }
    tr.visible-sm {
        display: table-row !important;
    }
    th.visible-sm,
    td.visible-sm {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem. I ended up replacing all col-md-* with col-xs-* and it worked like a charm. Here is the exmaple code

```
<div class="container make-border" id="obaidrehman07">
  <div class="row make-border">
    <div class="col-md-9 text-center main-title col-md-offset-1">
      <h4 class="heading-white"><strong>CONTRACT ACTION REPORT</strong></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-0 pull-right"> <img class="img-responsive" src="<?=$base_url;?>assets/office_home/target/dd46a999e4f329f98e5b8df60e21e9ab.png" alt="" style="max-width: 110px;" /> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

converted to

```
<div class="container make-border" id="obaidrehman07">
  <div class="row make-border">
    <div class="col-xs-9 text-center main-title col-xs-offset-1">
      <h4 class="heading-white"><strong>CONTRACT ACTION REPORT</strong></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-0 pull-right"> <img class="img-responsive" src="<?=$base_url;?>assets/office_home/target/dd46a999e4f329f98e5b8df60e21e9ab.png" alt="" style="max-width: 110px;" /> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```