# Unable to display 3 columns in same row in printed page using bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to show three columns in printed page .It works in browser but when i did print preview, it displays only two columns in print preview page.

html

```
<div class="container main">
<div class="main_inner">
    <div class="row" >
          <div class="col-md-12" >
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="../img/logo.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <h2>
                <center><b><?php echo   $row['municipality_address'];?> नगरपालिका</b></center>
            </h2>
            <h3>
                <center><b>नगरकार्यपालिकाको कार्यालय</b></center>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="border_box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <b></b>
    </div>
```

css

```
.main{
margin-top: 10px;
border: 5px solid #00bfff;
}
.main_inner{
margin: 50px;
margin-top: 150px;
margin-bottom: 80px;
}
```

I want to display like this page in printed page.

[image: Expected page]

But it looks like this in print preview.

[image: Real page]

Comment: Your question is incomplete, the styles for border_box is not included and the html page is also not complete

Comment: Here is html page. https://dpaste.de/ynpZ and css page https://dpaste.de/T61Z#L11 @Bosco

Comment: @Prabina can you post rendered HTML(from view source) instead of the one with PHP?

Comment: Here is the source code dpaste.de/KRVU   @shrys

Comment: @Prabina [You could try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20244712/4051471)

Comment: I will try and inform you.  @shrys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the border_box not to come down at any occasion try making the division that contains the image,text,border_box (`col-md-12`) as flex by including

```
<div class="col-md-12">
```

to

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="display:flex;">
```

and it wont come down when you try to print it too

I have attached a link to the [codepen](https://codepen.io/ssharishkumar/pen/KKPMGeX)

And after adding that the border_box doesnt come below too.
I hope this is what you are looking for

[image]

Comment: I have other issue as well. Can I ask you? @XxSTREKxX

Comment: @Prabina you are not supposed to ask questions inside question. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts instead update and create a seperate question

Comment: Can I ask another question and tag link to you? @XxSTREKxX

Comment: @Prabina Just post question so that anyone can answer

Comment: Please help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57636023/unable-to-insert-data-from-dynamically-created-add-remove-fields-in-database-usi?noredirect=1#comment101724845_57636023  @XxSTREKxX