# Unable to insert data from dynamically created add remove fields in database using php

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to  insert data from dynamically created add remove fields in database using php but unable to do.I'm only able to insert data from original form.

My form lools similar like this.Please help me.

My data looks like this
[image]

```php
<?php
require_once "conn.php"; 
$ch_direction= $ch_direction_through==$reg_id="";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){  
    for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['ch_direction']); $i++ )
{
        $ch_direction = trim($_POST["ch_direction"][$i]);
        $ch_direction_through = trim($_POST["ch_direction_through"][$i]);
        $reg_id= $_POST['reg_id'][$i];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO bps_registration_charkilla (ch_direction, ch_direction_through,reg_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";   

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss",$ch_direction, $ch_direction_through, $reg_id);
            $reg_id=$reg_id;
            $ch_direction=$ch_direction; 
            $ch_direction_through=$ch_direction_through; 

            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                if(!empty($reg_id)){
                    $success = "Submitted form successfully sent";     
                    header("location: registration_detail.php?success=$success&id=".$reg_id);
                    exit();
                } else {
                    header("location: registration_detail.php");
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 15; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button clicf k
        e.preventDefault();

        if(x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $('.input_fields_wrap').append('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><div class="form-group"><label for="">City</label><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>" name="reg_id[]"><select name="ch_direction[]" class="form-control" ng-model="ch.ch_direction" required><option value="n">उत्तर</option>  <option value="e">पुर्व</option> <option value="s">दक्षिण</option><option selected="selected" value="w">पश्चिम</option> </select></div><div class="form-group"><label for="">Email</label><select name="ch_direction_through[]" class="form-control" ng-model="ch.ch_direction_through"><option value="front">Front</option><option value="back">Back</option><option value="left">Left</option><option selected="selected" value="right">Right</option></select></div></div><div style="cursor:pointer;background-color:red;" class="remove_field btn btn-info">Remove</div></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    });
});
```

Comment: What exactly you want to know? What doesn't work? What happens? What have you tried so far to resolve it?

Comment: I tried a lot to insert array of data. But i'm only able to insert data of single form  and not able to insert data from dynamically added form @mentallurg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have a header the code will insert single row and do the header to the requested file. So, remove both the header.

Answer (score 0):

You assign variables within a loop, but insert into database only once *after* the loop. Put your database insertion *into* the loop, as follows (I keep it short for better understanding of the idea):

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['ch_direction']); $i++ ) { // Here you start each loop
    $ch_direction = trim($_POST["ch_direction"][$i]);
    $ch_direction_through = trim($_POST["ch_direction_through"][$i]);
    $reg_id= $_POST['reg_id'][$i];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO bps_registration_charkilla (ch_direction, ch_direction_through,reg_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";   
    ...
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)) ... // Here you prepare the statement for the current element in the loop
    ...
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) ... // Here you actually insert current loop element into the database
    ...
} // End of the loop
```

Comment: I tried but still got same problem. I tried to solve by using foreach as well but still i got same issue . @mentallurg

Comment: 1. Then update you code in the question. Put there your most recent code. 2. Show us the data from the request that the client sends to your server.

Comment: When i var_dump inside the lopp , i got single data  and when i did var_dump outside loop , i got before one data.  @mentallurg

Comment: I mean HTTP request. What is the contents of your HTTP request? If you look at it, may be you will see that the clients sends actually only one set/record, and your loop is actually executed only once. The the problem would be on the client side.

Comment: I have changed the image of data. When I did print_r($_POST);die ; inside the loop, I got above data. @mentallurg